# Run different Ansible plays in parallel

Tags: ansible

I do deploys with Ansible. I have something like this:

```
- hosts: abc-servers
  serial:
    - 1
    - "100%"
  roles:
    - deploy

- hosts: xyz-servers
  serial:
    - 1
    - "100%"
  roles:
    - deploy
```

But then xyz does not start deploying until abc is all finished.

If I was OK with waiting for the first abc *or* xyz host to succeed and then deploying everything else, this would work:

```
- hosts: abc-servers:xyz-servers
  serial:
    - 1
    - "100%"
  roles:
    - deploy
```

But I want to wait for the first abc host before deploying the rest of abc, and I want to wait for the first xyz host before deploying the rest of xyz. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
- hosts: abc-servers[0]
  roles:
    - deploy

- hosts: xyz-servers[0]
  roles:
    - deploy

- hosts: abc-servers[1:]:xyz-servers[1:]
  roles:
    - deploy
```

Or run against all hosts `abc-servers:xyz-servers` in the last run, as the code should be idempotent. Then you can run the first time on a random host:

```
- hosts: "{{ groups['abc-servers'] | random }}"
  roles:
    - deploy

- hosts: "{{ groups['xyz-servers'] | random }}"
  roles:
    - deploy

- hosts: abc-servers:xyz-servers
  roles:
    - deploy
```

<sup>Or combine the two using a fact on localhost to store the random host index/name.</sup>